# python can't find '__main__' module in '.py' in Azure Pipelines

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

My goal is to deploy and run my python script from GitHub to my virtual machine via Azure Pipeline. My `azure-pipelines.yml` looks like this:

```
jobs: 
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: Test_script
  environment:
    name: deploymentenvironment
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  strategy:
      rolling:
        maxParallel: 2  #for percentages, mention as x%
        preDeploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
          - script: echo initialize, cleanup, backup, install certs
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: python3 $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/test_file.py
        routeTraffic:
          steps:
          - script: echo routing traffic
        postRouteTraffic:
          steps:
          - script: echo health check post-route traffic
        on:
          failure:
            steps:
            - script: echo Restore from backup! This is on failure
          success:
            steps:
            - script: echo Notify! This is on success
```

This returns an error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/ubuntu/azagent/_work/1/test_file.py'

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

If I place the `test_file.py` to the `/home/ubuntu` and replace the deployment script with the following: `script: python3 /home/ubuntu/test_file.py` the script does run smoothly.

If I move the `test_file.py` to another directory with `mv /home/ubuntu/azagent/_work/1/test_file.py /home/ubuntu` I can find an empty folder, not a `.py` file, named of `test_file.py`

**EDIT**

Screenshot from Jobs:

[image]

Comment: How's the structure of your Python project? If you run your project locally via command line, how's the result? Could you set variable `system.debug` to `true` and share the entire log.

Comment: Python project in GitHub contains only `azure-pipelines.yml` and `test_file.py`. When I run the `test_file.py` in command line, it works (prints a sentence at this point. I'm going to add the real script to GitHub later). Please find the logs here: [link](https://pastebin.com/NFZ36ifJ). For some reason, now the error is about not finding the `test_file.py`.

Comment: You may try using `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` in your script to see how's the result. If you still get failed build, please login to the agent machine, navigate to the location `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`, and run the script from command line locally to see how the result.

Comment: For some reason, that `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`  (`/home/ubuntu/azagent/_work/2/s/`) is empty. And I looked other directories under the `_work` folder and they seemed empty as well. I think, that those files are not even uploaded to my virtual machine. Do you know, what might be the reason?

Comment: Please check CheckOut log to see whether the project is checked out successfully. Could you share your entire log?

Comment: I don't have that log available. I assume that it should be in the `Jobs` part in the UI (I edited the original post to include the screenshot from what I have available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you can not get the source is because you use `download: current` to [download artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download) produced by the current pipeline run, but you didn't publish any artifact in current pipeline.

As deployment jobs doesn't automatically check out source code, you need either [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) the source in your deployment job,

```
       - checkout: self
```

or [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#publish) the sources to the artifact before downloading it.

```
      - publish: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        artifact: Artifact_Deploy
```